# Webscrape and download the most recent RStudio build

Tags: r, bash, web-scraping, rstudio, rstudio-server

Is it possible to scrape https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/ and download the most recent Ubuntu server version (RStudio Server 1.3.957 - Ubuntu 18/Debian 10 (64-bit)). The names keep changing and I would like to build an R script that does the downloading and updating automatically one per day for me.

R script or bash script would be perfect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we had that in `littler` for *years* as two scripts I run myself every once
in a while.  Could be generalized for different distro arguments I suppse.

See

- [getRStudioDesktop.r](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/getRStudioDesktop.r)
- [getRStudioServer.r](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/getRStudioServer.r)

Demo

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ getRStudioDesktop.r 
--2020-05-06 14:24:53--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-ide-build/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.315-
amd64.deb
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.216.28.190
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|52.216.28.190|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 124609040 (119M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘rstudio-1.4.315-amd64.deb’

rstudio-1.4.315-amd64.deb  100%[=====================================>] 118.84M  3.65MB/s    in 39s     

2020-05-06 14:25:32 (3.08 MB/s) - ‘rstudio-1.4.315-amd64.deb’ saved [124609040/124609040]

edd@rob:/tmp$ getRStudioServer.r 
--2020-05-06 14:25:40--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-ide-build/server/bionic/amd64/rstudio-server-1.
4.315-amd64.deb
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.216.200.197
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|52.216.200.197|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 60524622 (58M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘rstudio-server-1.4.315-amd64.deb’

rstudio-server-1.4.315-amd 100%[=====================================>]  57.72M  3.01MB/s    in 22s     

2020-05-06 14:26:02 (2.65 MB/s) - ‘rstudio-server-1.4.315-amd64.deb’ saved [60524622/60524622]

edd@rob:/tmp$
```

and of course

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ wajig install *1.4.315*deb     # a dpkg/apt/... wrapper I like
(Reading database ... 478943 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rstudio-1.4.315-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio (1.4.315) over (1.4.200) ...
Preparing to unpack rstudio-server-1.4.315-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio-server (1.4.315) over (1.4.200) ...
Setting up rstudio (1.4.315) ...
Setting up rstudio-server (1.4.315) ...
useradd: user 'rstudio-server' already exists
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rstudio-server.service → /lib/systemd/system/
rstudio-server.service.
● rstudio-server.service - RStudio Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-05-06 14:26:54 CDT; 1s ago
  Process: 7315 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7316 (rserver)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 6.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/rstudio-server.service
           └─7316 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver

May 06 14:26:54 rob systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
May 06 14:26:54 rob systemd[1]: Started RStudio Server.
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.63ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.10-1) ...
edd@rob:/tmp$
```